# Appearance profiles in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-plugin, appearance

I use 2 monitors - 21" external and 15" laptop's screen. Everytime I swap the screens (e.g when taking laptop to school/home) I have to set up font's size (on exteranl screen I prefer bigger fonts on laptop's smaller).

Is there any plugin on trick that provides appearnace profiles to Eclipse - so I could quickly just swap profiles when changing monitors?

Comment: Font setting is not supported to be imported/exported to a file. I think it doesn't have easy way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the eclipse preferences are stored in the workspace: if I'm right you could try to create a workspace for each "environment" you use and to import the exixxting project without phisically copying the files.